# Using jQuery/javascript with Google Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, google-forms

I am trying to use jQuery/javascript with an iframe containing google form. 
Here is the code snippet:

```
<body>
<iframe id="myFormFrame" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/smfjkafj809890dfafhfdfd/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="1750" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
<button id="mybtn">Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mybtn').click(function(){
        var m=document.getElementById("ss-form");
        alert(m.innerHTML);
    });
</script>
```

The button on click should give the innerHTML of the form(which on loading inside iFrame has an id of "ss-form"). But its not working. So what could be the reason(cross domain iframe?)?
And what is the way to make jQuery work with google forms?

If it helps, I am trying to put custom ajax validation in place(for example, the email id field must contain emails from a specific list obtained from different database).

**EDIT**

Well it looks like a cross domain issue. I had this doubt in mind. But after looking at [this](http://morning.am/tutorials/google-forms-and-jquery-validation/) article, it looks like possible.

Comment: you can't because it is a cross domain iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` searches the current document, not other documents loaded into frames.

If the framed document was on your own site then you could access the frame and then access the document (via `contentDocument`) first. Then call `getElementById` on that.

Since it is cross-origin, that will fail. The reasons for this are obvious if you consider what would happen if *Mallory's evil website* were to stick your bank's online banking site into a frame while you were logged in.

If you had the cooperation of Google (you don't) then you could pass messages between the frames using [`postmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

> Well it looks like a cross domain issue. I had this doubt in mind. But after looking at this article, it looks like possible.

They aren't using a form hosted by Google. They've used Google tools to design the form and then copied the HTML to their own site. If Google ever implement CSRF protection, that will break.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I have already upvoted and I know about the cross domain issue. Pls have a look at the edit.